# Initializing class member variables with expressions (concatenated string) in PHP

Tags: php

I'd like to initialize a class member var using an expression- by concatenating a string... Why is the following not possible...

```php
class aClass {
    const COMPANY_NAME = "A Company";
    var $COPYRIGHT_TEXT = "Copyright © 2011 " . COMPANY_NAME;  // syntax error on this line - why?
    var $COPYRIGHT_TEXT2 = "Copyright © 2011 " . "A Company";   // even a syntax error on this line
}
```

Thanks very much for your help.

Prembo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, because that is how PHP works.

Variables which is initialized statically in PHP (anything outside of a method) may be assigned to static values, but they cannot be assigned to anything which requires a function call (other than `array`). you can get around this by placing the initializations in the constructor.

Additionally, you should be using either self::COMPANY_NAME or aClass::COMPANY_NAME, and `var` has been out of style since PHP 4. Use public/protected/private (and static where appropriate).

Answer (score 3):

Because a value of the class property/constant can't be expression. Use constructor for these purposes.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->COPYRIGHT_TEXT = "Copyright © 2011 " . self::COMPANY_NAME;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, gleaned from [Static Function Variables and Concatenation in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976717/static-function-variables-and-concatenation-in-php) you can also use define as in:

```
define('THING', 'foo' . 'bar');
class Thing {
    static $MyVar = THING;
}
```