# How to include variable inside class and use it?

Tags: php

I can't understand as to why this variable isn't working inside this class, the following error shows up:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE)
```

I read that it should be used the following way: `$this->url()` but it doesn't seem like PHP allows variables nor superglobals inside classes, is there a way around this?

```
class socialCounter
{       
    public $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    public function getPlus() 
    {       
        $html =  file_get_contents( "https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=".urlencode($this->url());
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc = new DOMDocument();   $doc->loadHTML($html);
        $counter=$doc->getElementById('aggregateCount');
        return $counter->nodeValue;
    }

    public function getTweets(){
        $json = file_get_contents( "http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=".$this->url() );
        $ajsn = json_decode($json, true);
        $cont = $ajsn['count'];
        return $cont;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7088645/3647441

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHP manual page on properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> [The property] declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

---

To do what you're attempting, you can instead initialize it in the constructor:

```
class socialCounter
{
    public $url;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }

...
```

---

Note: you're also missing a closing parenthesis in `getPlus(){...}` at the end of your `$html =  file_get_contents(...` line.

Answer (score 2):

you should use superglobals inside a class like this

```
class socialCounter
{       
    private $_httphost;
    private $_phpself;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_httphost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $this->_phpself = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        //use these variables inside your class functions
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign `$url` variable like this.If you want to do that I think You should want to called it on constructor.

```
private $url;

public function __construct()
{        
    $this->url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
}
```

Try this.